# List folders at or below a given depth in Powershell

Tags: powershell, recursion, depth, directory-structure

I have a directory which contains a lot of folders. I want to list all folder (path) that go deeper than 2 levels. So in below case folder 1 & 2.

```
Directory/folder1
Directory/folder1/test1/test/testsub
Directory/folder1/test2
Directory/folder1/test3
Directory/folder2/blablabla/bla/1
Directory/folder3/test
Directory/folder4/test
Directory/folder5/test
```

I was trying the following:

```
$Depth = 3
$Path = "."

$Levels = "\*" * $Depth
$Folder = Get-Item $Path
$FolderFullName = $Folder.FullName
Resolve-Path $FolderFullName$Levels | Get-Item | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} | Write-Host
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution immediately below, which builds on your own, assumes that your intent is to **find those child directories whose subtrees exceed a given depth**.

If you instead want to find all directory paths that are at a given depth *or deeper*, see the bottom section.
Your approach cannot achieve that, because it finds directories at the given depth only, not also below.

---

Your own clever wildcard-based approach should work in principle, but:

- (a) it can be greatly streamlined.
- (b) additional work is needed to limit output to the distinct list of those child folders whose subtrees are too deep.

#### (a) Streamlining your approach:

```
$Depth = 3
$Path = '.'

$Levels = '/*' * $Depth
Get-ChildItem -Directory $Path/$Levels
```

- As in your own approach, `'/*' * $Depth` dynamically creates a multi-directory-level wildcard expression (e.g., `/*/*` for a `$Depth` of `2`) that can be appended to the input `$Path` to match only paths at that level.
- The `-Directory` switch (PSv3+) limits matching to directories only.

#### (b) Limiting output to the distinct set of top-level folder with too-deep subtrees:

```
$Depth = 3
$Path = '.'

$Levels = '/*' * $Depth
Get-ChildItem -Directory $Path/$Levels |
  ForEach-Object { ($_.FullName -split '[\\/]')[-$Depth] } |
    Select-Object -Unique
```

<sup>Note: Splitting by `[/\\]` - that is, by either `/` or `\` - makes the solution work on Unix-like platforms too (PowerShell *Core*); on Windows, `-split '\\'` (by an escaped `\`) is sufficient.</sup>

With your sample folder hierarchy, the above would yield:

```
folder1
folder2
```

- If you want the *full paths* instead, append 
  `| Convert-Path -LiteralPath { "$Path/$_" }`.
- If you want *directory-info objects* (`[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`) instead,  append 
  `| Get-Item -LiteralPath { "$Path/$_" }`.

---

#### Optional reading: Getting folders up to, at, or beyond a certain depth:

Note:

- Even though the solutions below target *folders* (directories), you can include *files* too by simply omitting `-Directory`, or target files only by replacing `-Directory` with `-File`.
- For simplicity, the commands implicitly target the current directory.

---

**At-a-*given-depth-only* logic:**

This is the same logic employed in the solution above; the following code lists folders at depth 2 *only*, i.e. those at the grandchild level (child directories of child directories) - note that, unlike with `Get-ChildItem -Depth`, depth counting starts with `1`, i.e. `1` refers to child directories:

```
$depth = 2 # grandchild directories only

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path ('*/' * $depth)
```

- To output *full paths*, enclose the `Get-ChildItem` command in `(...).FullName` or pipe it to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`.
- To output *relative paths* (e.g., `folder1/test1/test/testsub`), additional work is needed, because adding `-Name` will *not* work as expected in this case (it will output just the directory *names*):

```
$depth = 2 # grandchild directories

# Calculate the length of the path prefix for determining relative paths.
# (Using the current dir ($PWD) as the reference path here.)
$PrefixLen = (Convert-Path -LiteralPath $PWD).Length + 1

$Levels = '/*' * $Depth
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path ('*/' * $depth) |
  ForEach-Object { $_.FullName.Substring($PrefixLen) }
```

***Up-to*-a-given-depth logic:**

The **PSv5+ `-Depth`** parameter **limits `Get-ChildItem`'s recursion depth**, i.e., it only finds items up to the specified depth, but note that it is **depth `0`**, not `1` that represents the **immediate children**.
Note that use of `-Depth` *implies* `-Recurse`, though you may specify the latter as well.

For instance, to enumerate child folders and grandchild folders (2 levels) in the current directory, use:

```
$depth = 2 # child and grandchild directories

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Depth ($depth - 1)
```

- To output *full paths*, enclose the `Get-ChildItem` command in `(...).FullName` or pipe it to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`.
- To output *relative paths*, simply add the `-Name` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` call.

**At-a-*given-depth-or-deeper* logic:**

Limiting results to items at levels greater than or equal to a given depth requires a custom solution:

```
$depth = 2 # grandchild directories and below

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Name -Recurse |
  Where-Object { ($_ -split '[/\\]').Count -ge 2 } |
    Get-Item -LiteralPath { "$PWD/$_" }
```

<sup>If your input path isn't the (implied) current dir., substitute that path for `$PWD`.</sup>

- To output *full paths*, replace `Get-Item` with `Convert-Path`.
- To output *relative paths*, simply omit the `Get-Item` call.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a search from index of x to a certain index of a folder I am looking for which should allow you to search between 2 and beyond

```
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Folder1 -Recurse -Directory
```

> If you know the name of a folder that you want to be the max index
> you can search for its index then you can search between x index and max index

```
if($folder.name -eq "Admin")
{
    #Get the index of the known folder
    $folderIndex = $folder.FullName.ToString().Split('\\').Count
}
```

> Set the starting index in this example 2 you can add "***-and $folder.FullName.ToString().Split('\').Count -lt $folderIndex***" to get the folders between 2 and max index id

```
if($folder.FullName.ToString().Split('\\').Count -ge 2) 
{
    $folderIndex2 = $folder.FullName.ToString().Split('\\').Count
    $folder.FullName + ' Index ID:' + $folderIndex2
}
```

The output would show up as
PS C:\Users\Programmer>  $folder.FullName + ' Index ID:' + $folderIndex2

C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4 Index ID:5
The drive itself is counted as index 1

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
$Folders = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files' -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1 | 
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty fullname | 
     Sort-Object
$Folders
```

Comment: `-Depth 1` will limit the recursion to the first 2 levels, so you won't know which directories have subtrees that go _deeper_, which is what the OP is after.