# regex to ignore all text after the fifth occurrence of a '\' backslash

Tags: regex, windows, powershell

I have been trying to get to write a regex that ignores all text post the fifth occurrence of backslash, e.g below text; language in question is powershell
`\\Fileserver\Usershare$\Svr2008\Profiles\john.contoso.V2`
I made multiple attempts but no avail, the best i could do was match everything post usershare$, using `([^\$]*$)` which gives me `\\Fileserver\Usershare$`

I would like the output to be `\\Fileserver\Usershare$\svr2008`

Any help would be appreciated.

As suggested by Mik i tried `^\\\\([^\\]*\\){3}` and used it as

```
$Parent= \\Fileserver\Usershare$\Svr2008\Profiles\john.contoso.V2
$test = $parent -replace '^\\\\([^\\]*\\){3}'
$test
```

I get the below

```
Svr2008\Profiles\john.contoso.V2
```

However i require the part that didn't match, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: The regex does not "output" anything. It is a pattern matching tool. You can use it to replace the matched substring with some pattern. This is what you want: to replace anything after the fifth backslash with empty string?

Comment: Yep, I'm using the replace function in powershell post match

Comment: There's a non-regex solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029472/list-folders-at-or-below-a-given-depth-in-powershell. Depending on your script, it might be better to only obtain the items you need in the first place using e.g. Get-ChildItem -Path x -Depth 4

Comment: are you actually wanting just the path - with the file name removed?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: No i actually require the path with the file name as well as the parent directory of the file removed

Comment: @RohitKachroo - ah! i misunderstood your intent. have you looked at `Split-Path`? the  `-Parent` will return the parent dir. do that twice to get up two levels. also, if your path is a dirinfo object, you can use `$Dir.Parent.Parent`. lastly, you can use standard string split/join commands - >>> `$Test.Split('\')[0..4] -join '\'` <<< if `$Test` contains your posted path, the the output will be `\\Fileserver\Usershare$\Svr2008`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one (it assumes there are 5+ backslashes)

```
^\\\\([^\\]*\\){3}
```

It matches
`\\Fileserver\Usershare$\Svr2008\` in `\\Fileserver\Usershare$\Svr2008\Profiles\john.contoso.V2`

After doing `'\\Fileserver\Usershare$\Svr2008\Profiles\john.contoso.V2' -matches '^\\\\([^\\]*\\){3}'`, your desired string will be in `$matches[0]`

Comment: Works like a charm! But when i replace it removes the part i need, so $test = $parent -replace '^\\\\([^\\]*\\){3}' gives output as Profiles\john.contoso.V2.

Comment: I edited in some more info, your desired string will be in $matches[0]

Answer (score 0):

here's yet another way to get the job done. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- puts the path in a $Var
- splits on the `\` chars
- grabs the 1st five resulting items
- joins them with `\`

the code ...

```
$Test = '\\Fileserver\Usershare$\Svr2008\Profiles\john.contoso.V2'
$Test.Split('\')[0..4] -join '\'
```

output = `\\Fileserver\Usershare$\Svr2008`